# jQuery can't trigger change after updating DOM

Tags: jquery, ajax, triggers

I created some dependent dropdowns in a chain. The one at the top should fire multiple Ajax requests for each dropdowns below it.

I'm using jQuery 1.3.2 with [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) so event handlers *should* be bind for all reloaded DOM items, yet triggering change doesn't occur for newly updated elements.

What am I doing wrong over here?

```
function dropDown_CHILD()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'url':...,
        'data':...,
        'cache':false,
        'success':function(html){
            $('#CHILD_unavailable').empty();
            $('#CHILD').replaceWith(html);
        },
        'complete': function(request, status){
            $('#CHILD').trigger('change');
        },
        'error':function(a,b,c){alert('An error occurred, please try again.');}
    });

}
$('#PARENT').livequery('change', dropDown_CHILD);
```

And the same is generated for CHILD-OF-CHILD as well, so this should invoke its handler as well in `complete` function, shouldn't it?

**Update:** [Now you can see it on-the-fly.](http://dev.pestaa.hu/test/index.php?r=research/create)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you have a live test-case? That would really help.

Comment: I have to get approval from my client, that takes a while.

Comment: You could just duplicate it and remove any client-specific information :)

Comment: Here you go: http://dev.pestaa.hu/test/index.php?r=research/create

Comment: Can you give us instructions on where exactly it doesn't work? What do I click on, etc?

Comment: In my theory, if one changes the year it should update all dropdowns (even with warnings about non-available data).

Instead it only reloads a single child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this case by replacing the plugin with [Ajax Listen Plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylisten.html), which puts a listener right on document DOM object.

It is now aware of all instances regardless of how DOM updated.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "replaceWith" removes the element before inserting the replacement so your event gets unbound:

> When an element no longer matches a
>   selector the events Live Query bound
>   to it are unbound. The Live Query can
>   be expired which will no longer bind
>   anymore events and unbind all the
>   events it previously bound.
>   (livequery doc)

Comment: Replace removes the element for sure, but it adds another one with the very same ID as well. What other ways would you suggest?

Comment: As a workaround you could use the triggered function in replacement to the .trigger('change'). 

PS: do you reproduce the problem when the second select has 2 elements?

Comment: Triggered functions only know about parent and child item. It shouldn't know about child of child, since that is optional. And yes, the bug exists regardless of item counts.

Comment: Yes, trigger functions know about child and not child of child but you will get the same "cascade" using trigger function, I don't see why not (on sample code)